# Undefined reference error at link using extern keyword

Tags: c, linker, undefined-reference

I have a problem at link between two libraries libA.a (static) and libB.so (dynamic), created from C sources.

In one of the source files used to generate libB.so, I have the following functions :

```
static uint64_t unassigned_mem_read(void *opaque, hwaddr addr, unsigned size) { ... }
static void unassigned_mem_write(void *opaque, hwaddr addr, uint64_t val, unsigned size) { ... }
```

When I run `nm libB.so | grep unassigned_mem` I've got:

```
00000000004662a7 t unassigned_mem_read
0000000000466337 t unassigned_mem_write
```

And in a source file used for making libA.a, I've got:

```
extern uint64_t unassigned_mem_read(void *opaque, hwaddr addr, unsigned size);
extern void unassigned_mem_write(void *opaque, hwaddr addr, uint64_t val, unsigned size);
```

and a bit further these methods are called.

When I compile, everything is ok. But then at link, I have:

```
[build] qmg-mmio.c:47: undefined reference to 'unassigned_mem_read'
[build] qmg-mmio.c:84: undefined reference to 'unassigned_mem_write'
```

When I do `nm libA.a | grep unassigned_mem` I've got:

```
U unassigned_mem_read
U unassigned_mem_write
```

I link in this order: libB.so, libA.a.

As the symbols are the same, what can make them not being resolved?

Moreover when I compile all the sources together, then I have no problem at link. Is there a subtelty when linking a static and a dynamic library altogether that I miss?

Comment: Remove the `static` keyword from both functions, ie. export them.

Comment: Isn't there any other possibility? I would be very  pleased not touching the sources of libB.so... =/

Comment: No, there isn't.

Comment: Damn. Even adding a file? Like a header in project B?

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer btw.

Comment: The `static` keyword is used to define something as being file-scoped.  It specifically precludes an outside translation unit from seeing something that is `static`-qualified.

Comment: If you _really_ don't want to change `libB` _source_ [the easiest option], you might be able to use some object editing/linker tools to change `libB.so` so that you change the linkage from `t` (static/invisible) to `T` (global). If you can't find one, you could write your own small utility that uses library API calls (e.g. either `libelf.so` or `libbfd.so`) to do the heavy lifting. But, again, if _you_ have the source and _control_ it, you could try _building_ it with `-Dstatic=/**/`. That may work as well.

Comment: The `t` in the `nm` output means that the symbols are local, not global,
symbols defined in the `.text` section. So the linker cannot see them. That's
because they're declared `static.` See [`man nm`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For file-scope identifiers, the `static` keyword specifies *internal linkage*.  That means that the identifier and any associated definition are essentially private to the translation unit in which they appear.  Lest there be any confusion, note well that this is only peripherally related to "static libraries", and especially that functions in static libraries that are intended to be called directly by library users must *not* be declared `static`, as that directly and specifically prevents such calls.

Linkage is a property of identifiers, within their scopes, not of the objects or functions they identify, and not necessarily of the same identifier in other scopes.  Moreover, the same identifier can be associated with different objects and / or functions in different scopes.  In particular, an `extern`al declaration of a given identifier is associated with a different function or object than those associated with any internal declarations of the same identifier, so you cannot redefine an internal declaration appearing in one scope as an external one by adding a declaration in some other scope.

Since you seem reluctant to modify the library containing the functions you want to call, I'm supposing that it is provided by a third party.  In that case, you should understand that part of the point of declaring those functions `static` is so that *you*, the library user, *do not* call them directly.  They are not part of the library's external interface.

Comment: I understand. I have to make a choice about modifying the source or just find another way to do what I want with the exposed API.